# how to link a condition to a button

Tags: angular

In my angular app. I am using child and parent components. my child component has "readonly" attribute. my parent component has a button to edit. how can i link the edit button in parent component to readonly in childcomponent. when i click edit button i want to disable readonly option in my child component. please guide me on how can i implement this.

Child component

```
<form[formGroup]='childForm'>
    <div>
        <inputformControlName = "childttest" [readonly] =  "isreadonly">
    </div>
</form>
```

Parent component

```
<form[formGroup]='parentForm'>
<button (click)= disableReadonly()> </button>
    <childComponent [childForm]= "parentForm.controls.childForm" ></childComponent>
</form>
```

parent component TS

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.parentForm = this.FormBuilder.group({
        test1: [''],
        childForm: this.FormBuilder.group({
            childtest: ['']
        })
    });
    this.parentForm.controls.childForm.controls.childtest.setValue(this.data);
}

disableReadonly(){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var) and toggle the value of `isreadonly` in the button's event handler. Try the following

parent component template

```html
<form [formGroup]='parentForm'>
<button (click)="child.isreadonly = !child.isreadonly">Toggle child readonly</button>
  <childComponent #child [childForm]="parentForm.controls.childForm" ></childComponent>
</form>
```

Here `#child` is the template reference variable of the `childComponent` tag. The `isreadonly` should be `public` for it to work. If you wish to have it as `private` then you could make it an `Input()` and pass it similar to the `childForm` variable.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tkjyeb)

Comment: Hi, I tried but it is not working. if possible, can you please provide me a working example.

Comment: @rja: I've updated the answer to include a working example.